# Quartz.Net DailyTimeIntervalTriggerImpl with different time zone

Tags: c#, .net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

Right, this is a bit of a tricky one.

I would like to create a daily trigger (DailyTimeIntervalTriggerImpl) so that it runs everyday from **07:30** to **23:45**. 
The problem is, it must be run in the users specified timezone, in this case, lets say Tokyo time.

From my understanding, I need to convert the times into utc.

The example below, works fine, but the trigger will expire after the endTimeUTC. How can I ensure the trigger runs continuously?

**Note**: I have tried using the **StartTimeOfDay** and **EndTimeOfDay** property of DailyTimeIntervalTriggerImpl but I get strange fire times when I have converted them to UTC.
The problem I believe is because:

a)the start time in utc form (in this example) will be **12/31/2012 10:30:00 PM** and

b)the end time in utc is **1/1/2013 2:30:00 PM** (*the following day*).

The DailyTimeIntervalTriggerImpl **StartTimeOfDay** and **EndTimeOfDay** only takes the a TimeOfDay object which only takes into consideration the times and not day.

So it will be StartTimeOfDay = 10:30PM and EndTimeOfDay = 2:30PM which doesn't really make sense. Because the EndTimeOfDay should really be 2:30PM the following day.

Any ideas?

```
 var startTime = DateTime.Parse("2013/01/01 07:30:00");
 var endTime = DateTime.Parse("2013/01/01 23:45:00");

 var tokyoTimeZoneId = "Tokyo Standard Time";

 TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(tokyoTimeZoneId);

 var startDateTimeUtc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(startTime, timeZoneInfo);
 var endDateTimeUtc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(endTime, timeZoneInfo);

 var dailyTrigger = new DailyTimeIntervalTriggerImpl
  {
    RepeatIntervalUnit = IntervalUnit.Hour,
    DaysOfWeek = GetDays(), // method to get a Quartz.Collection.HashSet list
    RepeatInterval = 3, // every 3 hours
    Key = new TriggerKey(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "my-group"),
    StartTimeUtc = startDateTimeUtc,
    EndTimeUtc = endDateTimeUtc,
  };

  // Compute fire times just to show simulated fire times
  IList<DateTimeOffset> fireTimes = ComputeFireTimes(dailyTrigger, null, 10);

  foreach (var dateTimeOffset in fireTimes)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("utc:{0} tokyo:{1}", dateTimeOffset,
      TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dateTimeOffset.DateTime, timeZoneInfo));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var daysOfWeek = new Quartz.Collection.HashSet<System.DayOfWeek>() { System.DayOfWeek.Wednesday, System.DayOfWeek.Thursday, System.DayOfWeek.Friday };

DateTimeOffset startTime = DateBuilder.DateOf(0, 0, 0, 14, 1, 2013);
DateTimeOffset endTime = DateBuilder.DateOf(0, 0, 0, 20, 1, 2013);

TimeOfDay startTimeOfDay = TimeOfDay.HourMinuteAndSecondOfDay(7, 30, 0);
TimeOfDay endTimeOfDay = TimeOfDay.HourMinuteAndSecondOfDay(23, 45, 0);

var tokyoTimeZoneId = "Tokyo Standard Time";
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(tokyoTimeZoneId);

var dailyTrigger = new DailyTimeIntervalTriggerImpl
{
StartTimeUtc = startTime.ToUniversalTime(),
EndTimeUtc = endTime.ToUniversalTime(),
StartTimeOfDay = startTimeOfDay,
EndTimeOfDay = endTimeOfDay,
RepeatIntervalUnit = IntervalUnit.Hour,
DaysOfWeek = daysOfWeek,
RepeatInterval = 3,             // every 3 hours
TimeZone = timeZoneInfo,
Key = new TriggerKey(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "my-group"),
};

// Compute fire times just to show simulated fire times
IList<DateTimeOffset> fireTimes = TriggerUtils.ComputeFireTimes(dailyTrigger, null, 1000);

foreach (var dateTimeOffset in fireTimes)
{
Console.WriteLine("utc:{0} - tokyo:{1}", dateTimeOffset,
  TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dateTimeOffset.DateTime, timeZoneInfo));
}
```

**NOTE**:

I would suggest you to use the very latest version: 2.1.1

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! I just tried removing StartTimeUtc and EndTimeUtc and just keeping StartTimeOfDay and EndTimeOfDay, and it works! Looks like the latest Quartz version which takes a TimeZone info seems to do the trick.